# Check Linux CentOS VM disk freespace

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, scripting, centos

I am trying to modify the below script to check the disk space on Linux VM with Powershell Core installed.

Script:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\computers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $computerName = $_
    Write-Host "Processing $($computerName)"
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computerName -Query "SELECT DeviceID, FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3" |
        Sort-Object -Property DeviceID |
        Select-Object -Property @{n='ComputerName'; e={$computerName}}, DeviceID, @{n='FreeSpaceGB'; e={[math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace / 1GB), 2)}}
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Freespace.csv
```

The above script is working for Windows Server, but somehow it is not working for CentOS Linux, even after the system is joined to AD domain https://computingforgeeks.com/join-centos-rhel-system-to-active-directory-domain/ and I have installed PowerSHell Core for Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7

Comment: WMI stands for "Windows Management Instrumentation", so you are trying to use Windows features against Linux so that will probably not work. I think you will need to find another approach.

Comment: Maybe this can be something: https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Get_Linux_disk_space_report_in_PowerShell

Comment: @DanielBjörk, thank you for the reply. So how can I get it to send email alert?

Comment: You first need to establish an endpoint on the Linux VM you can communicate with. If the scope is specifically managing CIM (the generic name for the protocol framework implemented as WMI in Windows) resources on the Linux machine, you need a WS-Management server (like `OpenWSMan`). If you want to execute arbitrary commands on the linux vm from a remote PowerShell client, you'll need to configure [PSRP over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can I run it on CentOS Linux or it is only for Ubuntu?

Comment: Given its popularity I'd be surprised if there isn't a readily available `openwsman-server` package for CentOS - check your package manager?